# Is there a tool for building and analysing robots (kinematics, control) visually?

Tags: software, design, inverse-kinematics, research, kinematics

I am reading research papers about robotics and many of them follow the same pattern:

1. some construction is established
2. kinematical formulas are read from the mechanical structure
3. the state space is analysed (e.g. how far the robot can reach, what the maximum speed can be, what is left underspecified and how to handle such mathematically incorrect systems and so on)

Is there some tool or software product that can receive (as input) the mechanical structure and then output the kinematical formulas?  Preferably, it would provide some kind of plots, analysis, suggestions for optimal design parameters (e.g. length, angles of the sturcture, optimum parameters of motors and so on).  Does this exist?

Comment: I created a video where I show how to get the moving graphics of a mechanical arm
https://youtu.be/crJXUlzJ918

Answer (score 3):

[The Actin toolkit](http://www.energid.com/actin-simulation-advantages.htm) is the only one I know of that sounds like what you want.

It integrates with SolidWorks to provide the kind of analysis you are talking about.

Other people may know of other similar tools though.

Comment: I came here to mention Actin as well, don't know of any others though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SolidWorks, ADAMS, or CATIA software.
You can design your platform and analyses or make a formula for that with this software.

Comment: I created a video where I show how to get the moving graphics of a mechanical arm
https://youtu.be/crJXUlzJ918